# Test/unit to rspec converter for Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have some existing Ruby projects that use test/unit. I'd like to automatically convert them to RSpec, so that I can play around with that framework.

It needs to be able to run on OS X.

I've heard of Transpec, which automatically converts from an old version of RSpec to a newer version. Same concept, but I want to go from test/unit to RSpec.

I came across [rspecify](https://github.com/rubiety/rspecify), but the README, the number of commits, and other metrics suggests it's more a proof of concept than a popular gem.